# Cannot Update MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

I have a simple MYSQL DB where field_3 is a varchar Key value. I am trying to update database posting to two TIME fields called start and end.

However I keep getting this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: empd_end in C:\xampp\htdocs\b1\update.php on line 25
>   Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':12:00, end = WHERE field_3 = Berkay_Sebat@yahoo.com' at line 1

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];
$emp_end= $_POST['emp_end'];


$sql = "UPDATE usezas ".
       "SET start = $emp_salary, end = $empd_end".
       "WHERE field_3 = $emp_id" ;

mysql_select_db('db1');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">EMAIL</td>
<td><input name="emp_id" type="text" id="emp_id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Start TIME</td>
<td><input name="emp_salary" type="text" id="emp_salary"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">END TIME</td>
<td><input name="emp_end" type="text" id="emp_end"></td>
</tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For debugging issues with SQL statements, you could **`echo $sql;`** before submitting to the database. (You are going to find that string and datetime literals need to be enclosed in single quotes within a SQL statement. Those look like variables in your code, but in the SQL text you're sending to the database, they're literals.) Also, **mysql** interface is deprecated; new development should use either **mysqli** or **PDO**. Potentially unsafe values need to properly *escaped* when they are incorporated in SQL text. A better pattern is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space after the value of `end` also, you will need to wrap your variables with a quotes like the query below.

```
$sql = "UPDATE usezas ".
       "SET start = '$emp_salary', end = '$empd_end' ".
       "WHERE field_3 = $emp_id" ;
```

However, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You sure prepare your query and should be using either PDO or MySQLi extensions not the old mysql_query extension.

Comment: It says data updated sucessfully but for some reason the second value is not being posted into my db. The second value is $emp_end.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your php vals to ''

`$sql = "UPDATE usezas ".
       "SET start = '$emp_salary', end = '$empd_end'".
       " WHERE field_3 = '$emp_id'" ;`